# C# Property Info (PropertyType)

Tags: c#, .net, recursión

estoy intentando implementar una funcion recursiva, y estoy recorriendo un objeto que dentro tiene otros objetos, lo estoy recorriendo con un PropertyInfo, lo que necesito saber es si ese propertyinfo es de tipo "Objeto" y por ejemplo que no sea un string,ni un entero, ni otro tipo, que sea una clase u objeto. Les paso el codigo:

```
    private async Task recurseAndPrintProperties(Object ObjectToRecurse)
{       
    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in ObjectToRecurse.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (
            (pi.PropertyType.IsClass) && 
            !(pi.PropertyType.IsValueType)
            )
        {
            String name = $"{pi.Name}Id";
            Type Type = pi.GetType();
            var PropertyId = Convert.ToInt32(typeof(Type).GetProperty($"{name}"));

            var newObjetRecurse = ObjectToRecurse.GetType();
            
            DataContext.ChangeTracker.TrackGraph(
            ObjectToRecurse, node =>
            {
                var keyValue = PropertyId;

                if (keyValue == 0)
                {
                    node.Entry.State = EntityState.Added;
                }
                else if (keyValue < 0)
                {
                    //ObjectToRecurse.CurrentValue = -keyValue;
                    node.Entry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
                }
                else
                {
                    node.Entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
                }                     
            });
            recurseAndPrintProperties(ObjectToRecurse);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Nota Aclaratoria: Todo lo que diré no son hechos canónicos, sino más bien como yo entiendo que funcionan las cosas en C#*

Dicho lo anterior, para mí, todos los tipos de datos en C# son objetos, y creo que existe la confusión ya que en otros lenguajes esto no es así. Esto queda demostrado si creas una función de este tipo

```
void funcion(object obj)
```

En esa función tú puedes pasar como argumentos, int, strings, o cualquier otra cosa.

Los objetos provienen de clases, estructuras y registros (class,struct,record) y todos los objetos deben ser instanciados. Por ejemplo un `int` es de tipo struct y un string es de tipo `class`

Además existe el concepto de [primitivos](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.type.isprimitive?view=net-7.0), que a diferencia de otros lenguajes no es más que una bandera que tienen algunos tipo de datos.

Lo que tú quieres es realizar filtros a las propiedades para determinar que cumplen algunas características. Lamentablemente, creo que no existe una solución genérica que pueda ser implementada y dependerá de cada caso particular. Por ejemplo

**2) Filtrar por clase**

```
if(! pi.PropertyType.IsClass)
```

El problema es que si no es una clase, por ejemplo yo uso mucho struct y record

**2) Filtrar por primitivos**

```
if(! pi.PropertyType.IsPrimitive)
```

De esta manera filtramos todos [primitivos](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.type.isprimitive?view=net-7.0) que ya son varios. Lamentablemente nos queda fuera el string

**3) Filtrar el string**

```
if(  pi.PropertyType.Name.ToLower() != "string" )
```

El problema aquí, es que si existe otro tipo de datos que no sea primitivo además del string ¿Quién se conoce todos los tipos de datos?

**4) Filtrar por namespace**

```
if(  pi.PropertyType.Namespace.ToLower() != "system" )
```

Otro problema, y si hay otro tipo de dato que está fuera el namespace "System". Porque nuevamente ¿Quién se conoce todos los tipos y sus namespaces?

**5) Filtrar por namespace del ensamblado**

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
if( pi.PropertyType.AssemblyQualifiedName.StartsWith(assembly.GetName().Name))
```

Aquí podríamos buscar solo objetos que estén definidos en el ensamblado, pero que pasa si tienes separado el proyecto con dll's (blazor lo hace default)

---

Hasta aquí puedes ocupar una combinación de todos estos filtros para lograr lo que buscas. Además tienes IsValueType e IsEnum que te ayudan aun más. Y con mucho cuidado y pruebas debería resultar.

Pero en mi opinión la única forma infalible es crear un decorador

```
public class Evaluar : Attribute { }

public class algunaClase
{
  [Evaluar]
  public Otraclas otraclase {get;set;}
}
```

Y luego:

```
if( pi.GetCustomAttribute<Evaluar>() != null)
```

Comment: Gracias @Yussef , lo voy a probar y te comento ! Encontre otra forma de realizar lo que queria hacer igual, pero esto lo voy a probar porque puede ser que me sirva para un futuro para otras cosas! Muchas gracias y buen aporte!